# Why is the last array in my loop the only array to display in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array of arrays, and when I loop through the array the only one displayed is the last array.

Here is the code that loops through the arrays;

```
@events.each do |event|
  def get_sig_class_id(sig_id)
    IpsSignature.where('sig_id =?', sig_id).first.sig_class_id
  end
  sig_id = get_sig_class_id(event.signature)
  event_class_data.push(sig_id)
  @event_class_array = Array.new(event_class_data.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k,v| [k,v.count]})
  @event_class_array.each do |x|
    @event_class = x
  end
end
```

If I display `@event_class_array` in my view I get this `[[1, 54], [30, 1], [2, 1]]`

If I display `@event_class` in the view I only get `[2, 1]`

I'm looking to get `[1, 54], [30, 1], [2, 1]` with `@event_class` (single arrays, not an array of arrays as in `@event_class_array`, and not just the last one).

My displaying in the view is simply to see what data I'm getting returned, this will eventually end up in a Highcharts pie chart.

Here are my views, nothing much to see here..

```
<%= @event_class_array %>
```

and

```
<%= @event_class %>
```

Comment: That's hard to read. Why do you define a method in your loop? Also, you're setting event_class instead of appending to it.

Comment: What do you mean setting?

Comment: You're setting the value to x instead of appending to an array. Also, canonical Ruby would use map/collect instead of appending inside an each loop.

Comment: And I don't see the point of defining that method inside a loop.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, I'll move the methods. I'm new to development and I was getting undefined method errors, so thats how I got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  @event_class_array.each do |x|
    @event_class = x
  end
```

this code means that for each array, @event_class is rewrited with the x. So only the last one is stored there.

If you want to insert all arrays you should do

```
  @event_class = [] 
  @event_class_array.each do |x|
    @event_class << x
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@event_class_array.each do |x|
    @event_class = x
end
```

You're overwriting @event_class every time that line fires. Change it to something like

```
@event_class_array.each do |x|
    @event_class += x
end
```

And you should be good.